# MX-FS-03V one transmitter to many recivers

Tags: arduino, rf

I want to use MX-FS-03V RF module as single transmitter to many receivers. 
As this module sold as pairs I don't know if this works or not or any trick to do this.

i think the screw on the module could helps but I don't know if its working.

Quote: "Im using arduino"

Thanks in advance

**update:**  At last i found its working.  You need to do nothing.  only use one transmitter and many receivers.

Comment: More information from you would be useful.  Specifically, not everyone knows anything at all about your RF module.  You should at least include specs, photos, any other information that would help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

They only cost £1.69 (from [here](http://hobbycomponents.com/wireless/168-433mhz-wireless-modules-mx-fs-03v-mx-05)) as a pair and most of that cost will be for the receiver (because they are more complex than the transmitter): -

[image]

Transmitter at the top and more complex receiver at the bottom.

So, buy a few (a small outlay of £10) and experiment. There appears to be no data sheet for this device so it's impossible to say if the adjuster on the receiver will tune it precisely to a different transmitter but, for substantially less than the money I'd charge for giving this advice professionally you could find out yourself.

Comment: "Experiment" may be easy to an expert ... but not to noobs like me :(

Comment: @MohammadRezaHashemi use a tool (non metallic) and adjust the screw on the receiver if it doesn't "match up" with a transmitter from a different pair. If that doesn't work then without a data sheet there is no more advice. The cost to buy three pairs is minimal in the whole scheme of things but your profile doesn't tell me where you are from and it's impossible to guess if this might be too expensive as an experiment.